# How to login to a website and extract data using JSoup?

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

I'm trying to extract data from fantasy.premierleague.com/transfers

Using JSoup and the following code, I can extract links from the homepage. However, to access the transfers page, I need to log in.

What should I add to this simple code so that I can login and access the transfers page?

```
public class StatsCollector {

public static void main (String [] args){

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fantasy.premierleague.com/transfers").get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        System.out.println(links);
    }  

    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StatsCollector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`JSoup` is only HTML parser, what you need to authenticate is some HTMLClient (for example Selenium) which can do some actions on a page (write to textfields, click on buttons).